# How many geometrical isomers will be formed here?

Tags: isomers, cis-trans-isomerism

[image]

Can someone help me calculate the number of geometrical isomers in this compound? According to me there should be 3 isomers here but according to my teacher, there are 4.I believe that both EZ and ZE cases will be same here.

Comment: in EZ or ZE cases the double bond in the middle also becomes stereomeric hence bringing it back to 4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possible reason you are being led astray is related to the way the substituents on the right side of the tri-substituted double bond are drawn in a linear fashion. However, when the hydrogen and the n-propyl group are drawn with the proper hybridization, only four isomers are possible, as napstablook has stated in a Comment.
In trienes **1** and **2** the tri-substituted double bond is stereogenic with the (*Z*)-designation in the former and the (*E*)-designation in the latter. The (*Z*)-propenyl group has priority over the (*E*)-propenyl group. The tri-substituted double bond in trienes **3** and **4** is non-stereogenic owing to the presence of identical groups at one end of the tri-substituted double bond.

[image]